# How do I know when asynchronous JavaScript execution complete in Rhino

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

I have a JavaScript code, which calls some asynchronous API and it works great. But I also need to call other API to report when script execution completed. The issue is that `Context.evaluateString(...)` returns immediately, but script code continues to execute because its asynchronous nature. JS example:

```javascript
function f1(function (err, res) {
  function f2(function (err, res) {
    function f3(function (err, res) {
      handleResult(err, res);
      // ideally I need to know when handleResult(...) has completed execution
      // but Rhino's Context.evaluateString(...) returns immediately
      // after f1() is called, but script continues execution
    });
  });
});
```

Yes, I could add some method to script to call it from script when all operations done, and handle it on Java side, but this will force me to call it every time. This is just workaround.
But I need more generic way without applying any rules to script code.
Also, what if customer will forget to call say `sendResult()` from script? App on other side will wait for result forever. So I need bullet proof solution.

In iOS, using javascriptcore I just reacted when added to script engine top-level object destroyed, but in Java this trick doesn't work because unlike Objective-C/Swift, Java is not reference-counting but using GC and you never know when object will be deallocated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You'll need to edit your question to include your code. For more help see, [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: *"I also need to call other API to report when script execution completed"* So what is stopping you from doing that? Presumably the asynchronous API you're calling will call a JavaScript function upon completion, right? That function then does the "call other API to report". It's what you'd do if this was 100% JavaScript, and that hasn't changed just because you also have Java involved. If you want the JavaScript callback function to further call some Java code for followup, then just make the JavaScript code call a Java method.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks. Yes, I CAN do this workaround, but it doesn't look beautiful to me and will be used as last resort. I can't believe there is nothing in Rhino to notify about script execution completion. I want to keep scripts easier to customers and do more on Java side.

Comment: Does `handleResult` return a promise or accept a callback?

Comment: @3limin4t0r It is synchronous.

Comment: What workaround? You need to write some code for what to do when asynchronous operation completes. Whether that is a javascript function or a Java method doesn't really matter, though since you're writing the asynchronous call in JavaScript, you should write the callback there, even if it doesn't do anything other than calling a Java method. I don't see how that's a "workaround".

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience using Rhino, so take this answer with a grain of salt. However this answer might steer you in the right direction.

The [documentation](http://mozilla.github.io/rhino/javadoc/org/mozilla/javascript/Context.html#evaluateString-org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-int-java.lang.Object-) states:

> **evaluateString**
>
> ...
>
> **Returns:**
>
> the result of evaluating the string

So I would create a [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) that is returned by the JavaScript. Resolve the future after `handleResult` is executed. Then on the Java side, simply cast the result into the correct object, then [wait](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) for the value to be resolved.

```js
// create an empty task
const future = new java.util.concurrent.FutureTask(function () {});

f1(function (err, res) {
  f2(function (err, res) {
    f3(function (err, res) {
      handleResult(err, res);

      // run the empty task, doing nothing more than resolving the future
      future.run();
    });
  });
});

// return future to evaluateString
future;
```

You can find more info about Java objects in JavaScript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scripting_Java).

Comment: Thanks. This is not different from calling a special function from script to notify Java side. And I tried this and it works. But I would like to have notification from Rhino engine, not from script. This is workaround, but I need a concrete solution.